# How to extract texts from container elements while iterating over those container elements in selenium webdriver -python scraping

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape http://quotes.toscrape.com/. It contains several boxes on  a single page and each box contains one quote, name of the person who gave the quote and tags for that quote. Now this is what I have done in selenium webdriver using python:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://quotes.toscrape.com/")
sleep(2)
all_boxes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(r"//div[@class='quote']")
for each in all_boxes:
    print(each.find_element_by_xpath('//span').text) // to print the quote
```

What I have done here is pretty much simple to understand. I have selected all boxes on that page and then iterating for each box I am trying to print the quote contained in each box using required xpath as observed in the HTML structure. But the output obtained is not what is expected. The output prints only the quote contained in the first box every time even though I am iterating through each box.

The output is :

```
 “The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking.It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.” 
 “The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking.It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.” 
 “The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking.It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.” 
 “The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking.It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.” 
 “The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking.It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.” 
 “The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking.It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.” 
 “The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking.It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.” 
 “The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking.It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.” 
 “The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking.It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.” 
 “The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking.It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”
```

I not able to find whats going wrong here in this very specific approach. Please tell only what is going wrong in this very approach as I very well know other techniques of scraping with selenium or beautifulsoup library of python. I just want to know why the above coded approach is not working.

Comment: My guess is that you need to add a wait. Wait until all the elements that match your locator are visible and you will probably be good. You can also simplify your locator to use a CSS selector, `span.text` and you won't need the nested `.find_element_*`... just print `each.text`.

Comment: Buddy, I have given exactly what is wrong with your code in the answers and some genius downvoted it. Can you just make up for it?

Answer (score 0):

To scrape the website `http://quotes.toscrape.com/` and extract the quotes, you have to construct a *Locator Strategy* which will identify all the quotes on the webpage then induce *WebDriverWait* for *all the elements to be visible* and store them in a `List`. Finally, you can use the `text` method to extract all the texts following the solution below :

- Code Block :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://quotes.toscrape.com/")
  all_boxes = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='quote']/span[@class='text']")))
  for each in all_boxes:
      print(each.text)
  ```
- Console Output :

  ```
  “The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”
  “It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.”
  “There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.”
  “The person, be it gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a good novel, must be intolerably stupid.”
  “Imperfection is beauty, madness is genius and it's better to be absolutely ridiculous than absolutely boring.”
  “Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.”
  “It is better to be hated for what you are than to be loved for what you are not.”
  “I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.”
  “A woman is like a tea bag; you never know how strong it is until it's in hot water.”
  “A day without sunshine is like, you know, night.”
  ```

Comment: I understood your solution but Whats going wrong in my code setup. Whats the problem or reason that my code setup even after iterating through all the boxes prints only the first quote?

Comment: all_quotes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(r"//span[@class='text']") and then using                                                                                    
   for each in all_quotes:
         print(each.text)
                                                                                                                                          This also works but I specifically wanted to store the div box contents and then after storing, want to iterate through each box(div) to print quote which is stored in span[@class='text']. How to go about the same?

Comment: @SHUBHENDRAKUMAR In short there were exactly 2 issues as follows: 1) Once you invoke `get()` you need a **waiter** for the desired elements to be **visible** before collecting them. 2) Instead of grabbing the parent node as in `//div[@class='quote']` traverse to the exact child node as `By.XPATH, "//div[@class='quote']/span[@class='text']"` to collect the required elements.

Comment: I am still not getting whats wrong in my code.
In beautifulsoup library, we can iterate through each div container and in each container we can find whatever tags we require and their text. But if we try to find our required tags while interating through the container tags, in selenium python, then its not giving the result and printing the first div container , selected tag text only every time of iteration. Why is it so? and also I have tried introducing sufficient waits every time but still the code prints only the first div container&#39;s tag text.

Answer (score 0):

It is your xpath that is wrong under iteration. What you should have given is a relative path to the element you are currently iterating instead of the entire document. so instead of

```
each.find_element_by_xpath('//span').text
```

Put this

```
each.find_element_by_xpath('./span').text
```